# How to optimize the finding of divergences between 2 signals

Tags: programming, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to create an indicator that will find all the divergences between 2 signals.[image]

(A divergence being defined as t1, t2 such that one signal increases between t1 and t2 while the other decreases between t1 and t2).

The output of the function so far looks like this

[image]

But the problem is that is painfully slow when I am trying to use it with long signals. Could any of you guys help me to make it faster if is possible?

**UPDATE**

Some sample [data](https://github.com/Vildnex/Crypto_15m_data/tree/main/Data)

My code:

```
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas_ta


def find_divergence(price: pd.Series, indicator: pd.Series, width_divergence: int, order: int):
    div = pd.DataFrame(index=price.index)
    div[f'Berish_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = None
    div[f'Berish_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = None

    div[f'Bullish_idx_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = False
    div[f'Berish_idx_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = False

    prices_lows = SortedSet()

    for i in range(len(price)):
        price_data = price.values[0:i + 1]
        data = argrelextrema(price_data, np.less_equal, order=order)[0]
        if len(data) == 0:
            continue

        for j in range(len(data)):
            elem = data[-1 - j]
            if elem not in prices_lows:
                prices_lows.add(elem)
            else:
                break
        del data
        del price_data

    price_lows_idx = pd.Series(prices_lows)
    for idx_1 in range(price_lows_idx.size):
        min_price = price[price_lows_idx[idx_1]]
        min_indicator = indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_1]]

        for idx_2 in range(idx_1 + 1, idx_1 + width_divergence):
            if idx_2 >= price_lows_idx.size:
                break

            if price[price_lows_idx[idx_2]] < min_price:
                min_price = price[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]

            if indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_2]] < min_indicator:
                min_indicator = indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]

            consistency_price_rd = min_price == price[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]
            consistency_indicator_rd = min_indicator == indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_1]]

            consistency_price_hd = min_price == price[price_lows_idx[idx_1]]
            consistency_indicator_hd = min_indicator == indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]

            diff_price = price[price_lows_idx[idx_1]] - price[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]  # should be neg
            diff_indicator = indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_1]] - indicator[price_lows_idx[idx_2]]  # should be pos

            is_regular_divergence = diff_price > 0 and diff_indicator < 0
            is_hidden_divergence = diff_price < 0 and diff_indicator > 0

            if is_regular_divergence and consistency_price_rd and consistency_indicator_rd:
                div.loc[div.iloc[price_lows_idx[idx_2]].name, f'Bullish_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = f"{price_lows_idx[idx_1]} {price_lows_idx[idx_2]}"
                div.loc[div.iloc[price_lows_idx[idx_2]].name, f'Bullish_idx_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = True

            elif is_hidden_divergence and consistency_price_hd and consistency_indicator_hd:
                div.loc[div.iloc[price_lows_idx[idx_2]].name, f'Berish_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = f"{price_lows_idx[idx_1]} {price_lows_idx[idx_2]}"
                div.loc[div.iloc[price_lows_idx[idx_2]].name, f'Berish_idx_{width_divergence}_{order}'] = True
    return div


if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_files_path = "/home/vlad/Projects/__freqtrade-2022.3/user_data/data/binance"
    files = os.listdir(source_files_path)
    files_5m = [x for x in files if x.split("-")[1].split(".")[0] == "5m"]

    db_name = "database_divergence.db"
    if os.path.exists(db_name):
        os.remove(db_name)

    engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{db_name}', echo=False)
    for pair in tqdm(files_5m):
        full_name = os.path.join(source_files_path, pair)
        data = pd.read_json(full_name)
        data.rename(columns={0: 'date',
                             1: 'open',
                             2: 'high',
                             3: 'low',
                             4: 'close',
                             5: 'volume'},
                    inplace=True)
        data['date'] = data['date'].values.astype(dtype='datetime64[ms]')
        data = data.set_index('date')
        data.ta.macd(append=True)

        avg_price = (data['high'] + data['low']) / 2

        width = 100
        order = 10
        divergences = find_divergences_V2_ALL(avg_price, data.MACD_12_26_9, width, order)
        data = pd.concat([divergences, data], axis=1)
        data.drop(data.columns.difference(divergences.columns), axis=1, inplace=True)
        data.to_sql(f"{pair.split('-')[0]}_{width}_{order}", con=engine)
```

Comment: Since your question is about speed, this question might fit better on StackOverflow

Comment: my question is not necessarily about speed then is about a method to implement divergences in a faster way. Because divergences are something related to trading, I found it to be more suitable here.

Comment: OK. But if you're going to include code, you might want to include some sample data so that someone can run it.

Comment: I've updated my question, I've added a GitHub with some sample data